# Running Housekeeper scripts on a HA (Active/Passive)

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, high-availability

I have following scenario. previously I had only one server running the application and it had `housekeeper script` running to archive `log` files. Now we have implemented `HA` ( high availability) and, I want to know in this case, how the `script` should identify which server is running currently and then to run the `script` accordingly, `HA` is implemented in `active/passive` mode. There are 2 physical servers to support HA, if one is down , other one will be active.

Comment: also asked on superuser: http://superuser.com/q/460732/4714

Comment: What are you using to do your HA implementation. Simply retrieve the status from the LinuxHA or whatever else (add a if at the beginning of your script)

Answer (score -2):

Use this Shell ecript for high availability on passive server.

```
#!/bin/bash

crumb_id=$(curl -s 'http://locathost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=contact(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)' -u admin:admin)
curl -s -XPOST 'http://locathost:8080/reload' -u admin:admin -H "$crumb_id"
~
```